# How to fix error – "No Visible @interface for ARCamera"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to build a project that I [downloaded from git](https://github.com/StephenGuanqi/Unity-ARKit-Plugin) and I got some errors in the Xcode beta 9. 
I noticed that there are some things that are deprecated like `ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration` so I changed them and they were fixed. But I get an error that I can't fix, this is the part from the code:

```
matrix_float4x4 projectionMatrix = [frame.camera projectionMatrixWithViewportSize: nativeSize
                                    orientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
                                    zNear:(CGFloat)unityCameraNearZ 
                                    zFar:(CGFloat)unityCameraFarZ];
```

I could not fix this and I don't know what to do.
the error for that is this:

> No visible @interface for 'ARCamera' declares the selector 'projectionMatrixWithViewportSize:orientation:zNear:zFar

Hope you can help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should update your XCode from beta to a stable version.

As for

> No visible @interface for 'ARCamera' declares the selector 'projectionMatrixWithViewportSize:orientation:zNear:zFar

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera) is official Apple documentation about ARCamera class which shows that there is no method `projectionMatrixWithViewportSize:orientation:zNear:zFar` and it's most possibly was changed to [projectionMatrixForOrientation:viewportSize:zNear:zFar:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923539-projectionmatrixfororientation?language=objc). Signatures of this two methods requires the same parameters, so it won't be problem to replace the old method with a new one.